# Python (While and Elif statements) -Error checking math

Tags: python, arrays, if-statement, while-loop

this is only my 4th python program. I am struggling with elif and/or else  statements. I placed note in the code to explain my goal is to use an array (1 to 12) randomly no repeats, check right and wrong answers,keep score, track tries and print out total scores.I did an import numpy as np and random           as random

```
    print ('''                       Super Multiplication Master!
    This is a multiplication flashcard game in which you will be asked to
    multiply math facts. Be sure to study your times tables 1 to 12. Your
    attempts and score will be tallied. Try your best! You got this Math
    Master! If you need a break, press 'q' to quit\n'''  )

    input('Ready, set go! Press enter to continue')

    array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
    attempts = 0
    score = 0

    def multiplication_game(array):
      c= random.array
      b= random.array
      a = b*c
      d = int(input('What is '+b+ ' x ' +c+ '?: '))

    while a==d: 
        score = (score+5) 
        attempts = (attempts+1)
    elif a != d:
       print('sorry, the correct answer is ' + a)
       score = (score-5)
       attempts= (attempts +1)

q = input()
for q:
if score >= 35:
    print('You did great, you got '+score+ 'out of 40')
if score ==30 or score ==25:
    print('You are doing well you got' +score+ 'out of 40')
if score == 20:
    print ('Okay, you got' +score+ 'out of 40. You are halfway to being a master')
if score <= 15:
    print('Okay, you got' +score+ 'out of 40. A little more practice and you will become a master')
else break'
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I am learning from a book if that helps understand context. I am trying to wrap my head around it.

Comment: Something is wrong with your indentation... please make sure the code is correct and runs, and include all your imports too. Thanks! :-)

Comment: Your indentation is a mess, as noted, also your final line contains a syntax error

Answer (score 1):

You should look at your terminal about what error you had when you try to complier the file.It should tell you about the indentation problem in your file. You could use either tab or four space for your indentation and make it consistency.

Comment: Ok, thank you will do!

Answer (score 0):

Try importing the random library

---

```
import random
```